# Aggregation Query in Symfony & MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I'm working on a Symfony 6 project with MongoDB and facing an issue with an aggregation query.

My goal is to fetch **Game** documents filtered by season and a player name in the related GameLineUp collection.

Despite setting up the aggregation with **$lookup**, **$match**, **$unwind**, and **$facet** for pagination and count, the query returns 0 results.

The season is a field in Game, and the player is in **GameLineUp**. Here's the structure of my aggregation query:

- Match **Game** documents by **season**
- Lookup **GameLineUp** documents using **_id** and **game**
- Unwind the result
- Match by **player** in **GameLineUp**
- Apply pagination (**$skip** and **$limit**)
- Use **$facet** to combine results and count

I've double-checked field names and data types. Any insights or suggestions on what might be going wrong or how to debug this effectively would be greatly appreciated.

My code on **GameRepository**:

```
public function getPlayerGames(Player $player, Season $season, int $page = 1, int $limit = 30): Paginator
    {
        $aggregationBuilder = $this->createAggregationBuilder();
        $resultsPipeline    = clone $aggregationBuilder;
        $resultsPipeline
            ->match()
                ->field('season')->equals($season)
            ->lookup('lineUps')
            ->alias('lineUps')
            ->match()
            ->field('lineUps.player')->equals($player)
            ->sort(['dateTimeGame' => 'DESC'])
            ->skip(($page - 1) * $limit)
            ->limit($limit);

        // Count pipeline
        $countPipeline = clone $aggregationBuilder;
        $countPipeline
            ->match()
                ->field('season')->equals($season)
            ->lookup('lineUps')
            ->alias('lineUps')
            ->alias('lineUps')
            ->match()
                ->field('lineUps.player')->equals($player)
            ->group()
            ->field('_id')->expression(null)
            ->field('count')->sum(1);

        // Combine using facet
        $aggregationBuilder
            ->facet()
            ->field('results')
            ->pipeline($resultsPipeline)
            ->field('count')
            ->pipeline($countPipeline);

        return new Paginator(
            $aggregationBuilder->execute(),
            $this->dm->getUnitOfWork(),
            Game::class,
            $aggregationBuilder->getPipeline()
        );
    }
```